# Kafka: max.poll.interval.ms set to Integer.MAX_VALUE but application still timesout

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka-clients 2.5.1 and have a kafka streams application with the following properties:

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "1");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "3000");
```

On an average it takes 30 minutes for one of the record to process but after each time, the following error comes up and the application starts re-reading the message that it just had processed:

```
02-07-2021 02:09:31.026 [employee_groups-client-StreamThread-1] WARN  
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop - stream-thread 
[employee_groups-client-StreamThread-1] Detected task 0_0 that got migrated to another thread. 
This implies that this thread missed a rebalance and dropped out of the consumer group. Will 
try to rejoin the consumer group. Below is the detailed description of the task:
>TaskId: 0_0
>>  ProcessorTopology: 
>       KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000:
>           topics:     [us4lat-employee_group_migration1]
>           children:   [KSTREAM-FOREACH-0000000001]
>       KSTREAM-FOREACH-0000000001:
>Partitions [us4lat-employee_group_migration1-0]
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskMigratedException: Client request for task 0_0 has been 
fenced due to a rebalance
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:530) ~ 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:478) ~ 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:226) ~ 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:543) ~ 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at 
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:977) ~ 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:823) ~ 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) 
[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar!/:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed 
since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This 
means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured 
max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time 
message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by    
reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

If the max interval is set to Integer.MAX_VALUE then why does the aforementioned exception come up every 30 odd minutes as soon as the processing of the record is completed? How can I fix this? Am I missing something?
I have also verified from the Kafka-Stream logs that the value for max.poll.interval.ms is getting set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is almost certainly the result of this overflow bug: [KAFKA-13126](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13126)

Normally a member should never miss a rebalance when the `max.poll.interval.ms` is set to MAX_VALUE since the group coordinator will wait for up to that time for all members to rejoin the group. But this `joinGroupTimeout` is actually computed as `max.poll.interval.ms + JOIN_GROUP_TIMEOUT_LAPSE` -- it adds an extra 5 seconds to give the consumers some wiggle room to get their JoinGroup request to the broker after hitting the `max.poll.interval.ms` and calling poll() again.

Unfortunately, when the interval is already set to `MAX_VALUE`, this of course is going to overflow. In that case the `joinGroupTimeout` is fixed to the `request.timeout.ms` instead, which defaults to just 30s. So the consumers have just 30s to rejoin the group once a rebalance has been triggered for whatever reason. But because the poll interval is so high, they're only ever going to poll after they run out of records to process.

Normally that might not be so bad, since batches are typically small enough to be processed in seconds and the consumer will end up needing to poll() within that 30s anyways. If each record takes 30 minutes to process, as in your case, there's no such luck -- it's almost certainly not going to poll() within those 30s. Even worse, once it finally *does* call poll(), it will realize it dropped out and request to rejoin, triggering a new rebalance. Which will then likely cause another member to drop out, who will then trigger *another* rebalance upon polling, and so on.

I opened a fix for this luckily the workaround is simple: just decrease the `max.poll.interval.ms`. Setting it to `MAX_VALUE - 5000` should be sufficient, but you may want to try lowering it a few more notches to something more useful. Something like 2 * max_time_process_record * max.poll.records -- that way if something goes wrong and a consumer gets stuck while processing for whatever reason, then the group coordinator will notice and kick it out of the group so another consumer can resume work on its partitions. Without waiting for Integer.MAX_VALUE ms to pass, that is.